# Add data to linked table - MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have a table called 'person' with existing data and also a primary key of 'personID'. After I had inserted data into this table I created another table to set up a relation which was named 'person_address' which stores the foreign keys of both the 'person' and 'address' table.

Basically my issue is I want to insert data from the person table into the foreign key as these were created after. Can I do this without having to stop the keys being Auto Incrementing and also will they continue to update by themselves afterwards when data is added?

Answer (score 0):

Try Writing a Stored [Procedure](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php).
In this procedure you can write an update query.i.e When you update 'person' table then the 'person_address' table will also be updated where personID is joined.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: Yeah Sure.If it solves your problem accept the answer.